# Delete row when glyphicon is clicked

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is the userTable.php where the table is viewed

 When the user clicks on the glyphicon remove, a message should appear saying that the row has been deleted but when I click on it, it redirects to a blank page and the url

```
<?php
  $welcome="Hello, " . $name ."!";

  include("../db/dbconn.php");

  $sql = "SELECT artistCD.cdID, artistCD.cdTitle, artistcd.cdPrice, 
sdetails.qty, sum(artistCD.cdPrice * sdetails.qty)
  as TotalSales FROM artistCD NATURAL JOIN sdetails NATURAL JOIN cdsales 
WHERE 
day(cdSales.dSales) = day(Now()) AND
  month(cdSales.dSales)=month(Now()) AND year(cdSales.dSales)=year(Now()) 
AND 
 cdSales.uID = '$uID' GROUP BY artistCD.cdID";
  //WHERE ORNum
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  $total = null;
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "
      <tr>
        <td>".$row["cdID"]."</td><td>".$row["cdTitle"]."</td>
<td>".$row["cdPrice"]."</td><td>".$row["qty"]."</td>
<td>".$row["TotalSales"]."</td>
        <td>
        <a href='artistcd.php?action=edit&cdID='".$row['cdID']."><i 
class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'>&nbsp;</i></a>
        <a href='../util/deleteRow.php?
action=cdID='".$row['cdID']."title='Are you sure you want to remove this CD?
        data-toggle='confirmation' data-singleton='true' data-
placement='left' data-popout='true'>
          <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'>&nbsp;</i></a>
        </td>
      </tr>";
      $total += $row["TotalSales"];
      $GLOBALS['total'] = $total;
  }
  echo"
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td><td></td><td class='text-right'>Grand Total:</td>
<td>".$total.".00</td><td></td>
  </tr>";
  }
  else{
echo "No records found.";
  }
 $conn->close();
?>
```

This is the deleteRow.php where the delete query is found.

```
  <?php
  //MySQL Database Connect
  include("../db/dbconn.php");

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET")
    {
            // get the 'id' variable from the URL
            $id = isset($_GET['cdID']);

            $sql = "DELETE FROM sdetails WHERE cdID = '$id'";

            $result = $conn->query($sql);


    }
?>
```

Comment: You should not write database code in the same place where you write UI code. I suggest you using MVC or MVP patterns.

Comment: make href # value. then use maybe default javascript alert? and then if confirm, direct the user to the deleteRow.php file

Comment: @Troyer fixed the anchor. But it still redirects to a black page and no message.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
<?php
    $welcome = "Hello, " .
               $name .
               "!";

    include( "../db/dbconn.php" );

    $sql = "SELECT artistCD.cdID,
                   artistCD.cdTitle,
                   artistCD.cdPrice,
                   sdetails.qty,
                   SUM( artistCD.cdPrice *
                        sdetails.qty ) AS TotalSales
            FROM artistCD
            NATURAL JOIN sdetails
            NATURAL JOIN cdsales
            WHERE DATE( cdSales.dSales ) = CURDATE()
              AND cdSales.uID = '$uID'
            GROUP BY artistCD.cdID";

    $result = $conn->query( $sql );
    $total = null;
    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 )
    {
        // output data of each row
        while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() )
        {
            echo "<TR>\n
                      <TD>" . $row[ "cdID" ] . "</TD>\n
                      <TD>" . $row[ "cdTitle" ] . "</TD>\n
                      <TD>" . $row[ "cdPrice" ] . "</TD>\n
                      <TD>" . $row[ "qty" ] . "</TD>\n
                      <TD>" . $row[ "TotalSales" ] . "</TD>\n
                      <TD>\n
                          <A HREF = 'artistcd.php?action=edit&cdID=" .
                                     $row[ 'cdID' ] .
                                     "'>\n
                              <I CLASS = 'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'>&nbsp;</I>\n
                          </A>\n\n

                          <A HREF = '../util/deleteRow.php?action=cdID=" .
                                     $row[ 'cdID' ] .
                                     "
                             TITLE = 'Are you sure you want to remove this CD?'
                             DATA-TOGGLE = 'confirmation'
                             DATA-SINGLETON = 'true'
                             DATA-PLACEMENT = 'left'
                             DATA-POPOUT = 'true' >\n
                              <I CLASS = 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove'>&nbsp;</I>\n
                          </A>\n
                      </TD>\n
                  </TR>\n";
            $total += $row[ "TotalSales" ];
            $GLOBALS[ 'total' ] = $total;
        }

        echo "<TR>\n
                  <TD></TD>\n
                  <TD></TD>\n
                  <TD></TD>\n
                  <TD CLASS = 'text-right'>Grand Total:</TD>\n
                  <TD>" .
             $total .
             ".00</TD>\n
              <TD></TD>\n
              </TR>\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No records found.";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Note : I changed the layout to make it easier to debug.  Rather than return the layout to what you were using, I have left mine in as a suggestion.

Note : Your usage of single and double quotes was a bit patchy.  I have tried to tidy that up.

Note : I have changed the WHERE clause in your MySQL statement to be a bit more effeicient.  See [DATE()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date.asp) and [CURDATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) for more information.

Note : Your second HREF does not set action to a value.  You may wish to choose one.

If you have any questions or comments about my answer then please feel free to post a comment accordingly.